# Java - Lock down TLS version in java.security, but allow per app override via launch config?

Tags: java, ssl

I've got a bunch of java apps that run on a single server.

I'd like to disable TLSv1 and other insecure protocols by default for all apps on the server, but allow some apps to override this using a command line argument.

For example, I can use a line like so in my `java.security` file in the JVM to disable TLSv1 for all apps by default.

```
jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms=TLSv1, SSLv3
```

I then tried to use the `jdk.tls.client.protocols` property to enable it for some apps, but it doesnt seem to override what was set in the JRE.

e.g. This doesn't use TLSv1 if I've disabled it in `java.security`

```
java -Djdk.tls.client.protocols=TLSv1 MyTestApp
```

Can this be done? Or do I need to take a different approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears I can use the following command line arg to do this. I thought I'd tried this recently and it didn't work, but I tried again today and it seems to ;-)

`java -Djava.security.properties=disabled_tlsv1.properties MyTestApp`

where `disabled_tlsv1.properties` is a file that contains the same line you would've put in your `java.security` file

#### disabled_tlsv1.properties

```
jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms=TLSv1, SSLv3, RC4
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume you meant the commandline option to be `-D...` (with hyphen); `D...` doesn't work.

Yes, the security properties take precedence. The only way to re-enable TLSv1 is to change the security property, <strike>and there is no standard option for that.</strike> correction: you're right, but I'll leave this as an alternate.

What you could do is write [an agent](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/instrument/package-summary.html) which calls `Security.setProperty()` (at JVM startup) invoked by a `-javaagent` commandline option. Note this applies JVM-wide; different apps can be different only if/when they are in different JVM processes.

Comment: Thanks for the info... I played around quite a piece today trying to get this all to work and then found that option I mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51429397/26510) and it seems to work for me... Thanks a bunch for the help!